# Selecting an account and server on the same screen

Tags: mobile, android, material-design

I have an app that allows the user to add and select multiple accounts and servers, and switch between them.

Here's what I have currently:

[image]

The account and server boxes are swipe-able pagers, and the rightmost entry is always a plus sign, as follows:

[image]

Tapping either plus sign opens a wizard to add an account or server.
If there was more than one account or server, the pager would have those before the 'add' pages.

This approach feels wrong somehow, and it uses a *lot* of space. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: A question first: does each card need so much space? Isn't a vertical list (with icons, like android contact list) effective?

Comment: @adriano I don't think they really need this much space, but I also don't see a way a vertical list could work; it would end up being two vertical scrolling lists on the same screen, which seems like it would be worse than the current approach, or it would be three screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiping elements mechanism is not obvious for me. I would tweak it a little by turning each Account/Server into an icon, which will scroll horizontally.

[image: Wireframe 01]

This is only a draft idea - you can make icons a little bit bigger, if you need more description underneath each of it, you can add context menus when long-pressing an icon, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use two Dropdown lists to select from the list of accounts and servers.It makes good use of space and makes things simpler for the user.

Comment: I've considered using a dropdown, but they don't seem to work very well on a mobile device in general, especially if they get long enough to start scrolling. I'll try it anyway, and see if it works better.